# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. React-Native 0.72.8

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, mobile

I can build on ios platform succesfully. But i need to try build in android but i cant always i got the thesee errors. How can i resolve theese bugs?

Error =

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android:.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.facebook.react:hermes-android:.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find any matches for com.facebook.react:react-native:+ as no versions of com.facebook.react:react-native are available.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-community_geolocation
         project :app > project :react-native-community_slider
         project :app > project :react-native-firebase_analytics
         project :app > project :react-native-firebase_app
         project :app > project :react-native-firebase_crashlytics
         project :app > project :react-native-firebase_messaging
         project :app > project :react-native-picker_picker

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I use Macbook Air M1.

Java version = OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.9+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17.0.9+0, mixed mode, sharing)

Node js. version = v20.9.0

My android/build.gradle =

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "2.2.3"
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"

    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
        }
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }


    }
}
```

My android/app/build.gralde =

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false


def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'


def getVersionCodeFromNpm() {
    //  Read and parse package.json file from project root
    def inputFile = new File("$rootDir/../package.json")
    def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)

    // Return the version, you can get any value this way
    return packageJson["majorVersion"]
}

def nativeArchitectures = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDebugArchitectures")
apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sekizc.sporsimdi"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode project.hasProperty('versionCode') ? project.property('versionCode') as int : 1
        versionName project.hasProperty('versionName') ? project.property('versionName') : "0.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'mlkit'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            /* if (project.hasProperty('SPORSIMDI_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(SPORSIMDI_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword SPORSIMDI_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias SPORSIMDI_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword SPORSIMDI_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            } */
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
             if (nativeArchitectures) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters nativeArchitectures.split(',')
                }
            }
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
                unstrippedNativeLibsDir 'build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib'
            }
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release

}


dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'

    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

My package.json =

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "xxx",
  "majorVersion": xxx,
  "private": true,
  "currentVariant": "xxxx",
  "variants": {
 
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean-project": "npx react-native-clean-project",
    "android": "npx react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "ios-14": "pnx react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 14 Pro Max'",
    "start": "npx react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "clean": "watchman watch-del-all",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.1.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.2",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.6",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.1.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.6.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.6.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^18.6.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.6.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.16.8",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.202",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.10",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.19",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1",
    "i18next": "^22.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "lottie-ios": "3.4.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.8",
    "react-native-macos": "0.72.10",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-barcode-mask": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.4",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1128.0",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.6",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.1.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.8.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.2",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-maps": "0.29.3",
    "react-native-mask-input": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-month-year-picker": "^1.8.1",
    "react-native-multicolor-progress-bar": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.4",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.4.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.0.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.17.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0",
    "react-native-shake": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.8.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-text-input-mask": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.8.1",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^3.6.6",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.6.0",
    "react-native-week-view": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-worklets-core": "^0.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "vision-camera-code-scanner": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-native-text-input-mask": "^0.7.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.54.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

My paths =

```
export JAVA_HOME="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.9/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home"

export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"

alias sail='bash vendor/bin/sail
```